# How would I transpile non-UI portions of a C# UWP app to JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, uwp, transpiler

I want to be very clear that I am not asking how to transpile a C# UWP app to a JavaScript UWP app. I am, rather, attempting to extract portions of an existing C# UWP application that can be migrated to create a Node.js server. I attempted to use [Bridge.NET](https://bridge.net/), but my impression (correct me if I'm wrong) is that there is no way to build an app that targets both UWP and .NET. If there is, this alone would likely solve my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be possible using the [Uno Platform](https://platform.uno/); see [this blog post](https://ian.bebbs.co.uk/posts/UnoLinux). Alternatively, have a look at [this workaround](https://github.com/microsoft/ProjectReunion/issues/105).